# does quote removal happen after command substitution in a POSIX shell?

Tags: shell, posix

The POSIX shell standard at

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04

says in Section 2.6:

```
command substitution (...) shall be performed

(...)

Quote removal (...) shall always be performed last.
```

It appears to me that quote removal is not performed after command substitution:

```
$ echo "#"
#
$ echo '"'
"
```

as expected, but

```
$ echo $(echo '"')#"
>
```

What am I not understanding?

Added after reading answer/comments:

From what everybody is saying, the consideration of quotes happens at the very beginning of parsing, for example, to decide if a command is even "acceptable".  Then why does the standard bother to emphasise, that the quote *removal* is performed late in the process??

Comment: `echo $(echo '"')#"` is not a valid command because of unbalanced quoting hence shell is still waiting for your input to complete the quote.

Comment: @anubhava that's what I don't understand - according to the standard, quoting should not even be considered before command substitution - so first, the command inside the substation is legitimate, yields `"` on standard output, and then the outer command becomes `echo "#"` and is balanced.

Comment: Shell interpreter has to accept the complete command before attempting command substitution or word splitting. In this case shell is still waiting for your input to complete the command.

Comment: @anubhava where does it say in the standard what a "complete command" is?

Comment: Section 2.4 'Token Recognition' on the page you link to probably covers what you're after.

Comment: 2.3  .  Yes I have been trying to "parse" (pun intended) this section for a while and so far I have not completely succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"then the outer command becomes `echo "#"` and is balanced"*

That is not 'balanced' because the first double-quote does *not* count.  Quotes are only meaningful as quotes if they appear unencumbered on the command line.

To verify, let's look at this:

```
$ echo $(echo '"')#
"#
```

That is balanced because the shell does considers that `"` to be just another character.

By contrast, this is unbalanced because it has one and only one shell-active `"`:

```
$ echo $(echo '"')#"
>
```

#### Similar example 1

Here we show the same thing but using *parameter expansion* instead of *command substitution*:

```
$ q='"'; echo $q
"
```

Once the shell has substituted `"` for `$q`, one might think that there was an unbalanced double-quote.  But, that double-quote was the results of *parameter expansion* and is therefore *not* a shell-active quote.

#### Similar example 2

Let's consider a directory containing `file`:

```
$ ls 
file
$ ls "file"
file
```

As you can see above, quote removal is perfomed before `ls` is run.

But, consider this command:

```
$ echo ls $(echo '"file"')
ls "file"
```

As you can see `ls $(echo '"file"')` expands to `ls "file"` which is the command which ran successfully above.  Now, let's try running that:

```
$ ls $(echo '"file"')
ls: cannot access '"file"': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the shell does not treat the double-quotes that remain after command substitution.  This is because those quotes are not considered to be shell-active.  As a consequence, they are treated as normal characters and passed on to `ls` which complains that the file whose name begins and ends with `"` does not exist in the directory.

The same is happening here:

```
$ cmd='ls "file"'
$ $cmd
ls: cannot access '"file"': No such file or directory
```

#### POSIX standard

From the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06):

> Enclosing characters in single-quotes ( ' ' ) shall preserve the
>   literal value of each character within the single-quotes

In other words, once the double-quote appears inside single quotes, it has no special powers: it is just another character.

The standard also mentions escaping and double-quotes as methods of preserving "the literal value" of a character.

#### Practical consequences

People new to shell often want to store a command in a variable as in the `cmd='ls "file"'` example above.  But, because quotes and other shell-active characters cease to be shell active once they are stored in a variable, the complex cases always fail.  This leads to a classic essay:

["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: where are the terms "unencumbered" and "shell-active" explained in the standard?

Comment: I am trying to understand very hard what you are saying (because I don't see it in the standard, so your words are the only thing I have).

Comment: I think I understand, I will accept this.  If I change my mind later, I will unaccept :)

Comment: The documentation is not clear.  I use "unencumbered" to refer to a character that is not escaped and not quoted.  I use "shell-active" to mean that the shell treats character specially.  The documentation talks about the reverse: circumstances that "preserve the literal value of a character".  Because I find the that phrasing awkward, I chose different words to express the ideas.